# Why Jruby RubyKernel.java throws exceptions 'LoadError/ NameError when cli.debug = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

My jruby version is 9.0.3.0.

While running specs of my rails app with

> '-Xcli.debug=true'

following exceptions are raised.

```
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- pg_array_parser
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- rspec-http
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- strong_parameters
Exception `NameError' at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/jruby-9.0.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:534 - uninitialized constant Addressable
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- idn
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- idn
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- http
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- httpclient
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- patron
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- curb
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- em-http-request
Exception `NameError' at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/jruby-9.0.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:534 - uninitialized constant EventMachine
Exception `NameError' at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/jruby-9.0.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:534 - uninitialized constant EventMachine
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- typhoeus
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- excon
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- manticore
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- tzinfo/data
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- action_view/test_case/test_helper
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- action_view/test_case/test_helper
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - No such file to load -- action_view/test_case/test_helper
Exception `AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError' at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/jruby-9.0.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:151 - Missing helper file helpers/action_view/test_case/test_helper.rb
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- capybara/rspec
Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 - no such file to load -- capybara/rails
```

Comment: If you analyze the output... `no such file to load`. Seems it trying to load files from another root location that no exists

Comment: @JuanjoSalvador I have analyzed that, but my all specs passing, these are only exceptions.

Comment: @JuanjoSalvador can you suggest any way to set or reset the root location ?

Comment: A simple search in Google... https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/420#issuecomment-160631470

You can debug your code using `--debug` while running it instead using  '-Xcli.debug=true' and get the same coverage.

Comment: @JuanjoSalvador I know that --debug will get me coverage without printing these errors. But I want to know the real reason behind these exceptions.
Till now I have understood that they are related to how Rails initialize all requirements. Any further comments are welcome.